# Javascript indexOf a specific instance of a character

Tags: javascript, regex

A simple question that is hard to Google effectively, so apologies for that!

I have a URL in a string, like so:

```
 var url = https://foo.com/give/me/HELP/9835'
```

I'd like to create a substring using Javascript that returns the "HELP" portion of the string. The simplest way of doing this I can think of is getting the index of the 5th and 6th `/` and creating a substring around it, but I can't find documentation on how to do this.

And ideas?

Comment: Why not a simple split? `var r = 'https://foo.com/give/me/HELP/9835'.split('/')[5]`

Comment: Oh! I had no idea you could pass in an index number to split like that. Great, thanks!

Comment: @Jascination: This is not _“pass[ing] in an index number to split”_, this is simply accessing the 6th element in the array that split returns.

Answer (score 0):

[`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) takes a `fromIndex` as its second parameter - you can simply find the first four occurrences and then search from that index:

```
function findNthOccurrenceOf(search, n, string) {
  var i = 0, j = 0, l = string.length;
  while (j++ < n) {
    i = string.indexOf(search, i) + 1;
    if (i === 0) { i = -1; break; }
    if (i >= l) break;
  }
  return i > 0 && i < l ? i - 1 : -1;
}
```

However, that's a bit overkill for such a scenario.  You could also just split the string by the delimiter and get the value at index N:

```
> var splitArray = 'https://foo.com/give/me/HELP/9835'.split('/')
["https:", "", "foo.com", "give", "me", "HELP", "9835"]

> splitArray.length > 4 ? splitArray[5] : "MISSING"
"HELP"
```

Or use a regular expression if the expected value will always be in a certain format:

```
> var search = /\/(HELP)\//.exec(url);
["/HELP/", "HELP"]

> search ? search[1] : "MISSING"
"HELP"
```